# How to display exact value using google.visualization.Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I'm having trouble displaying exact values using google.visualization.Table

Please see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71p2usnb/) for my example.

It seems that it defaults to 3 decimal places despite more exact values being provided. I want to show the entire value (e.g. 0.000001).

Below is the data I used:

```
 data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 0.01}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v: 0.001},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 0.0001}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 0.00001},  true]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the table will display the formatted value by default

using object notation, you can provide both the value (`v:`) and formatted value (`f:`)

e.g. --> `{v: 0.00001, f: '0.00001'}`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawTable,
  packages:['table']
});

function drawTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
  data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mike',  {v: 0.01, f: '0.01'}, true],
    ['Jim',   {v: 0.001, f: '0.001'},  false],
    ['Alice', {v: 0.0001, f: '0.0001'}, true],
    ['Bob',   {v: 0.00001, f: '0.00001'},  true]
  ]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: works great, thanks. I just have to integrate into my JSON now since I'm populating it with that.